# Google Calendar Refuse Login Password

Tags: macos, calendar, gmail, password, ical

Out of no where the iCal 7 refused to sync with Google by prompting me to input password upon launched.

I tried both Google account password and application-specific password but no availability.

The error log I gotten from the Console are below:

> 9/9/14 5:35:52.541 PM CalendarAgent[373]:
>   [com.apple.calendar.store.log.caldav.queue] [Account refresh failed
>   with error: Error Domain=CoreDAVHTTPStatusErrorDomain Code=401 "The
>   operation couldn’t be completed. (CoreDAVHTTPStatusErrorDomain error
>   401.)" UserInfo=0x7fe79c00f3b0 {AccountName=myemail@gmail.com, CalDAVErrFromRefresh=YES, CoreDAVHTTPHeaders={type = immutable dict, count = 12,
>   entries =>    0 : Content-Type = {contents = "application/vnd.google.gdata.error+xml;
>   charset=UTF-8"}   4 : alternate-protocol = {contents = "443:quic"}  5 : Content-Encoding = gzip
>     6 : Server = GSE    7 : x-xss-protection = {contents = "1; mode=block"}     8 : Expires = {contents = "Tue, 09 Sep 2014 09:35:49
>   GMT"}     12 : Cache-Control = {contents = "private, max-age=0"}    13 : Date =
>   {contents = "Tue, 09 Sep
>   2014 09:35:49 GMT"}   15 : Content-Length = 210   19 :
>   x-content-type-options = nosniff  21 : x-frame-options = {contents = "SAMEORIGIN"}     22 :
>   Www-Authenticate = {contents
>   = "GoogleLogin realm="https://accounts.google.com/ClientLogin", service="cl""} } }]

I have no issue accessing other Google services on the Mavericks and via browser.

Anybody can help? Thanks

Comment: Could you take the time and CLEAN up that Console copy/paste. It is unreadable the way it is now.

Answer (score 1):

Go to **System Preferences > Internet Accounts**, remove your *Google* account and add it back again.

*WARNING: This operation will eliminate all the data related to your account stored in your computer and will download a fresh copy (email, contacts, messages, etc.)*